Name of movie? Bearskin Rug - Lady can't say Safari, keeps saying something like "fasari"
This is a tough one that my Dad asked of me.  He can't remember the name of the movie and this is the distinct part he remembers:

The lady is on a bearskin rug having a conversation and she says
  (keeps saying?) fasari instead of Safari. It's considered a funny
  moment, which back then probably was.

He was born in 1940, so I'm assuming it's a movie from late 1940's through 1960's.
Not much to go on, but thought I'd try here.
Additional information after reading guidelines about asking this type of question:

US Movie
He's not sure if it was b/w or color.
He doesn't recall the names of the actors, otherwise this whole quest would likely be easier.  However, the main actors were caucasian and spoke English (he believes American English, but it could possibly have been British English).


That's easy. It was the original Pink Panther movie. The lady in question was Claudia Cardinale.



There is also a reason why he thought they may have been speaking British English. Peter Sellers (Clouseau), and David Niven (Sir Charles Lytton) were among several British actors in the cast.

Of course it's not a bearskin... but I think it was probably this anyway. :-)

Though Seller's does not speak in a British accent in any of the Pink Panther movies.
